# mutual Scroll Bar

Tags: c#

I have two rich text boxes, and I want to use just one scroll bar that will control them both.

How can I do that?

Please Help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

See [this example](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/scrollingTextbox.aspx).